# elementary problem in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and $R$ be a set defined by $$\{(x,y)\in X\times X: \text{$x$ and $y$ have the same remainder when divided by $3$}\}$$  Then what's the numbers of elements in $R$?  My approach is

$\bar{0} = \{3,6,9\}$ so we can get $2!\binom{3}{2}$ numbers of elements

$\bar{0}= \{1,4,7,10\}$ we get $2!\binom{4}{2}$ elements

$\bar{2} = \{2,5,8\}$ we get $2!\binom{3}{2}$ elements

Now counting all the elements like $(1,1),(2,2)$ and so on..., I get the answer $34$.  Is it correct?

Comment: $R=\{(x,y)\in X\times X$: $x$ and $ y$ have the same remainder when divided by $3\}$?

Comment: The answer is correct. Btw, it equals $3^2+4^2+3^2$ (an easyer way).

Comment: @ henry sorry for my  mistake its a typing mistake

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct.

$R\subset X\times X$ can be recognized as an equivalence relation. As comes forward in your question its equivalence classes are $\{3,6,9\}$, $\{1,4,7,10\}$ and $\{2,5,8\}$.

Then: $$R=\left[\{3,6,9\}\times\{3,6,9\}\right]\cup\left[\{1,4,7,10\}\times\{1,4,7,10\}\right]\cup\left[\{2,5,8\}\times\{2,5,8\}\right]$$

And its cardinality is $3^2+4^2+3^2=34$

Comment: whats your thought about this quick elegant solution?

Comment: Every equivalence relation $R$ induces a partion of equivalence classes. If $C$ is an equivalence class then each pair $(p,q)$ with $p,q\in C$ will belong to $R$. If $p,q$ are ements that are *not* in the same class then $(p,q)\notin R$.

Comment: thanks its very much helpfull

Comment: You are welcome.